# Load entity after login, and navigate to entityID

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, ngrx, ngrx-effects

**Flow:**

After the user successfully logs in, the app should load users **Vendor** and navigate to **VendorID**

Example: 
*myUrl.com/vendor/ID*

**Different cases I'm trying to support:**

**1. A user puts it URL with Vendor ID:**

App will reload Vendor

**2. After login**

App will load the Vendor and Navigate to URL

**3. On refresh**

App will re-load Vendor, and only navigate if URL does not exist already of VendorID (So the user will stay on the same page he is already at)

**My issue:**

When a user refreshes the app, he will be re-navigated to root Vendor (Not good, I want him to stay on his page, navigate only on login)

**Code I have tried so far:**

```
 @Effect()
  loadVendor(): Observable<VendorDataInitAction | AuthAction | VendorDataAction> {
    return this._actions$
      .pipe(
        ofType<AuthLoginSuccessAction | AuthRefreshSuccessAction>(AuthActions.LoginSuccess, AuthActions.RefreshSuccess),
        withLatestFrom(this._store.select(selectAuthActor)),
        filter(([_, actor]) => isUserLoggedIn(actor)),
        switchMap(([_, actor]) => {
          const errorActions = [
            new AuthSetAuthMessageAction({
              message: 'You need to be granted access in order to login to Portal.\n' +
                'Please contact your Platterz representative.',
              type: AuthMessageType.Error
            }),
            new AuthLogoutAction()
          ];

          return this._apollo
            .query<AssociatedRestaurants>({
              query: AssociatedRestaurantsQuery
            })
            .pipe(
              switchMap((result): ObservableInput<AuthAction | VendorDataAction> => {
                const errors = result.errors && result.errors.length > 0;
                const noRestaurants = !(result.data && result.data.associatedLocations &&
                  result.data.associatedLocations.locations.length);

                if (errors || noRestaurants) {
                  return errorActions;
                }

                return [
                  new VendorDataInitAction(result.data.associatedLocations.locations)
                ];
              }),
              catchError(() => errorActions)
            );
        }));
  }

  @Effect()
  navigateToVendorOnDataLoad(): Observable<VendorDidSetIDURLAction> {
    return this._actions$
      .pipe(
        ofType<VendorDidSetIDURLAction>(VendorDataActions.Init),
        withLatestFrom(this._route.params.pipe(map((params) => params.vendorID))),
        filter(([, vendorId]) => vendorId == null),
        switchMap(() => this._store.select(selectCurrentVendor)),
        filter((vendor) => !!vendor),
        take(1),
        map((vendor) => {

// When trying to get Route params, and navigate only if VendorID is null, Its always null...

          this._router.navigate(['/vendors', vendor.id, 'dashboard']);

          return new VendorDidSetIDURLAction();
        })
      );
  }
```

I tried accessing **Route** params on **@Effect** with no success, it does not contain **VendorID** while refreshing...

How is it possible to get **Route** params from **@Effect**? Or is there a better way of archiving this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting my solution for anyone else bumping to a similar issue.*

Seems as URL params are not accessible at times from **@Effects** (Specifically on refresh) So I used local storage instead.

Flow goes as the following:

1. By default, the app will always navigate you to **sign-in** page in case you do not have any URL params (Enter base app URL)
2. Any auth component has a **CanActive** guard, that checks for logged in state, if logged in, navigates to current Vendor, if not, **sign-in** will be displayed.

**First route:**

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AppLoggedOutGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'sign-in',
        component: LoginPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-up',
        data: { signUpBenefits },
        component: VendorSignUpComponent
      }
    ]
  },
```

**LoggedOut guard**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppLoggedOutGuard extends AppRoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    store: Store<IAppState>,
    router: Router,
    private _appAuthService: AppAuthService
    ) {
    super(router, store);
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._user$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(() => this._appAuthService.getLoggedInState()),
        map((isLoggedIn) => {
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            this._navigateToVendor();

            return false;
          }

          return true;
        })
      );
  }

  private _navigateToVendor(): void {
    this._store.select(selectCurrentVendor)
      .pipe(
        filter((vendor) => !!vendor),
        take(1)
      ).subscribe((vendor) => {
        this._router.navigate(['/vendors', vendor.id, 'dashboard']);
      });
  }
}
```

For fetching extra data, you can use a resolver on the Vendor(Or you entity) base component